# Mutate dataframe in R add column which shows a change of other column in percentage

Tags: r

I'm searching for an easy way to add a new column to a dataframe which will show a `change` of a particular variable (i.e. `emission`) over time (`year`) in regard to a group (`fips`) compared to the **first record** (in first record `change` is exactly NA).

So, in example, in Baltimore City, 2002 emissions where `52%` lower compared to the `1999`. In the `2005`, emissions where lower (we still compare it to the `1999`)

**Data**

```
> str(motor_compare_general)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year     : int  1999 1999 2002 2002 2005 2005 2008 2008
 $ fips     : chr  "Baltimore City, Maryland" "Los Angeles County" "Baltimore City, Maryland" "Los Angeles County" ...
 $ emissions: num  404 6110 192 7189 185 ...
> motor_compare_general
  year                     fips emissions
1 1999 Baltimore City, Maryland  403.7700
2 1999       Los Angeles County 6109.6900
3 2002 Baltimore City, Maryland  192.0078
4 2002       Los Angeles County 7188.6802
5 2005 Baltimore City, Maryland  185.4144
6 2005       Los Angeles County 7304.1149
7 2008 Baltimore City, Maryland  138.2402
8 2008       Los Angeles County 6421.0170
```

**Should be**

```
> new_motor_compare_general
  year                     fips emissions change
1 1999 Baltimore City, Maryland  403.7700 NA
2 1999       Los Angeles County 6109.6900 NA
3 2002 Baltimore City, Maryland  192.0078 -52%
4 2002       Los Angeles County 7188.6802 +17%
5 2005 Baltimore City, Maryland  185.4144 -54%
6 2005       Los Angeles County 7304.1149 +20%
7 2008 Baltimore City, Maryland  138.2402 -66%
8 2008       Los Angeles County 6421.0170 +5%
```

I calculated values in *change* column by hand to show what I'm looking for

This problem probably can be solved very easy by *tidyr* or *dplyr*, but I cannot find a proper method for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With dplyr : `group_by` city and create the new variable.

```
d<- read.table(text='
year                        fips   emissions
1999   "Baltimore City, Maryland"  403.7700
1999   "Los Angeles County"        6109.6900
2002   "Baltimore City, Maryland"  192.0078
2002   "Los Angeles County"        7188.6802
2005   "Baltimore City, Maryland"  185.4144
2005   "Los Angeles County"        7304.1149
2008   "Baltimore City, Maryland"  138.2402
2008   "Los Angeles County"        6421.0170',head=TRUE)

library(dplyr)

d %>% group_by(fips) %>%
   mutate(change=((emissions / dplyr::first(emissions,order_by=year))-1) *100)

## with % formating :
d %>% group_by(fips) %>% 
  mutate(change=
           paste0(round(((emissions / dplyr::first(emissions,order_by=year))-1) *100),"%"))

  year                     fips emissions change
1 1999 Baltimore City, Maryland  403.7700     0%
2 1999       Los Angeles County 6109.6900     0%
3 2002 Baltimore City, Maryland  192.0078   -52%
4 2002       Los Angeles County 7188.6802    18%
5 2005 Baltimore City, Maryland  185.4144   -54%
6 2005       Los Angeles County 7304.1149    20%
7 2008 Baltimore City, Maryland  138.2402   -66%
8 2008       Los Angeles County 6421.0170     5%
```

Comment: First observations are "0%", not NAs as required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(
"year fips emissions
1999 \"Baltimore City, Maryland\" 403.7700
1999 \"Los Angeles County\" 6109.6900
2002 \"Baltimore City, Maryland\" 192.0078
2002 \"Los Angeles County\" 7188.6802
2005 \"Baltimore City, Maryland\" 185.4144
2005 \"Los Angeles County\" 7304.1149
2008 \"Baltimore City, Maryland\" 138.2402
2008 \"Los Angeles County\" 6421.0170
"
)

setkey(DT, year, fips)

DT[, change0 := (emissions/head(emissions, 1) - 1), by = fips]

DT[, change := sprintf("%1.0f%%", 100*change0)][, change0 := NULL]
DT[, change := ifelse(year == min(year), NA, change), by = fips]

DT
   year                     fips emissions change
1: 1999 Baltimore City, Maryland  403.7700     NA
2: 1999       Los Angeles County 6109.6900     NA
3: 2002 Baltimore City, Maryland  192.0078   -52%
4: 2002       Los Angeles County 7188.6802    18%
5: 2005 Baltimore City, Maryland  185.4144   -54%
6: 2005       Los Angeles County 7304.1149    20%
7: 2008 Baltimore City, Maryland  138.2402   -66%
8: 2008       Los Angeles County 6421.0170     5%
```